# Kafka Monitoring JMX Attributes Count or MeanRate?

Tags: jmx, apache-kafka, jmxtrans

I have configured jmxtrans to get the values from `"kafka.server":type="BrokerTopicMetrics",name="AllTopicsMessagesInPerSec"`

It has 3 attributes- `Count , OneMinuteRate, MeanRate`

I am confused to identify, which of these attributes gives the `"Number of Messages into the Broker Per Sec"`?

Sample values I got for these attibutes at an instance are

```
Count =1955600, MeanRate = 1036 , OneMinuteRate=2643
```

Which of these attributes should I refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will be **MeanRate**.

OneMinuteRate - means average value of MeanRate for last 60 seconds